# Services which provide web-login for embedded content editing/versioning

Tags: authentication, github, static-site

I am building a static application aiming for zero-costs apart from static content distribution, and for potential user interaction would like to embed a service which allows versioned edits to embedded content. Ideally, I would have liked to have used github, for instance to submit content directly from specific pages, but github uses OAuth 2.0 which would require some kind of backend process. Google and FB have web logins but the types of content embedding they provide aren't particularly useful (unless I am mistaken).

My question is what other options are out there that might provide git-based embedded content. Ideally not bloatware.

Just to stress that I am not interested in any kind of service like Cognito or Firebase or oauth.io.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I strongly believe that you discarded the OAuth2 provider too soon. And, I might say, you do not need a backend to use an OAuth authenticator.

OAuth2 has some "flows" you can choose from. The most common demands an backend, since its authentication uses a `refresh token` to renew the `access tokens` and your backend should do that. You can find a good start point about the flows here:

https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/which-oauth-flow-to-use

In your case, I believe you are looking for `Client Credentials Flow` (or the `Resource Owner Password Credentials Flow`). Particularly, from the context I got, I would recommend you to seek the `Client Credentials Flow`. This flow do not have a Refresh Token and you can authenticate your application just from a client perspective (running on a browser, for instance) and do not require any backend service. Most of OAuth2 providers supports this flow. What happens in this flow is that every time the client reloads or access your site and the `access token` is expired it will re-authenticate via the OAuth provider (or you could even automatize this and add some transparency to your client). A little bit more:

https://nordicapis.com/8-types-of-oauth-flows-and-powers/

Hope it helps!

Comment: The problem is that OAuth2 providers are expensive for a project with no budget, especially given that most charge per request and not per user. Do you recommend any provider? AWS cognito is cheap but it has a lot of issues so I am avoiding it. Firebase and oauth.io are too expensive.

Comment: Well, I was under the impression that you would use a service like Github for this. If not, can you describe with some more details what you want to achieve? But if it's the case, for instance, you would use the web-application-flow, described here: https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps/#web-application-flow

Comment: The problem is that you can't send requests to https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token from the browser because that would mean having the client secret publicly available.